# Query to return rows according to column conditon

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query where given a table of users with a column name (for ex) "Likes", i want to select all those users that have records with both a 0 and a 1 for the "Likes" column. The schema looks something like this:

```
id  Name  Likes
0   Tom   1
1   Alice 0
2   Tom   0
```

The query should return rows with id = 0 and id = 2 since Tom has both a 1 and a 0 for the Like column. What is the simplest/most efficient query to accomplish this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `tab`, you can use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab a
 WHERE (SELECT count(distinct b.likes)
         FROM tab b
        WHERE a.name = b.name
          AND b.likes in(0, 1)
       ) = 2
```

This can easily be extended to any number of distinct likes that are required. Just enumerate them in the `IN` clause, and compare the subselect to the number of values.

Comment: I get your idea but you should rather join, I think.

Comment: @peter.petrov I do not understand why you want to join. BTW: Many database optimizers handle a subselect like an outer join, and in this case - if the table has records at all - the `outer` of teh outer join will never happen.

Comment: OK, could be. Just making sure you did it on purpose this way.

Comment: @peter.petrov I find it easy to understand this way, and there is no need for an explicit `GROUP BY` which you would need when you use joins.

Answer (score 2):

If `Likes` can be only 1 or 0 in your table and nothing else, you can do this.

```
select distinct t1.Name From tableName t1
join tableName t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.Likes = 1 - t2.Likes
```

If that is not the case, just do this:

```
select distinct t1.Name From tableName t1
join tableName t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.Likes = 1 and t2.Likes = 0
```

Another possible solution is this one.

```
select a.* from
tableName a 
JOIN 
(
    select b.Name, count(distinct b.likes) as Likes
    from tableName b
    group by b.Name
    having count(distinct b.likes) > 1
) a1 on a.Name = a1.Name
```